# How to perform this refactoring in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm working with functions generated by `servant-client` and trying to wrap them in a custom monad. I have a function generated by `servant-client` with the following signature:

```haskell
getDomain
    :: AuthenticateReq (AuthProtect "x-api-key")
    -> Maybe Int
    -> Maybe Int
    -> Manager
    -> BaseUrl
    -> ExceptT ServantError IO Domain
```

and a following wrapper around it:

```haskell
domain
  :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadError ServantError m)
  => Int -> m (Domain)
domain domId = do
  auth <- mkAuth
  manager <- asks envManager
  url <- asks envBaseUrl
  baseUrl <- parseBaseUrl url
  r <-
    liftIO $ runExceptT $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing manager baseUrl
  case r of
    Left e -> throwError e
    Right x -> return x
```

As I will have a number of such functions and wrappers I would like to extract a helper function which would:

- take a servant-generated function applied to all but last two arguments
- using MonadReader grab manager and baseUrl, feed it to the servant function and return it fully applied

My attempt so far looks as follows:

```haskell
helper
  :: (Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadReader Env m, MonadThrow m)
  => (Manager -> BaseUrl -> m b) -> m b
helper f =  do
  manager <- asks envManager
  url <- asks envBaseUrl
  baseUrl <- parseBaseUrl url
  f manager baseUrl
```

but unfortunately it doesn't compile due to following error:

```
Could not deduce (MonadReader Env IO)
  arising from a use of ‘helper’
from the context (MonadReader Env m,
                  MonadIO m,
                  MonadThrow m,
                  MonadError ServantError m)
  bound by the type signature for
             domain :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m,
                        MonadError ServantError m) =>
                       Int -> m Domain
```

and I don't understand why the compiler is infering MonadReader Env IO constraint. I would like to know why that's happening and what would be proper way to do this refactoring if it is possible at all. Would I need to make any changes to the `domain` function itself to accommodate this change?

---

**UPDATE:**

refactored version of `domain` is below:

```haskell
domain
  :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadError ServantError m)
  => Int -> m (Domain)
domain domId = do
  auth <- mkAuth
  r <-
    liftIO $ runExceptT $ helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing
  case r of
    Left e -> throwError e
    Right x -> return x
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I have now arrived at a solution that:

- appears to compile and work
- I admit I don't really understand

```haskell
domain
  :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadError ServantError m)
  => Int -> m (Domain)
domain domId = do
  auth <- mkAuth
  helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing

helper
  :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadError e m)
  => (Manager -> BaseUrl -> ExceptT e IO b) -> m b
helper f = do
  env <- ask
  r <- liftIO $ runExceptT $ runReaderT (helper1 f) env
  case r of
    Left e -> throwError e
    Right x -> return x

-- based on
-- https://github.com/passy/giphy-api/blob/4b006db2fe566b7200f6c81b8c56cabe2a595b90/src/Web/Giphy.hs#L359
helper1
  :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t, MonadThrow (t m), MonadReader Env (t m))
  => (Manager -> BaseUrl -> m b) -> t m b
helper1 f = do
  manager <- asks envManager
  url <- asks envBaseUrl
  baseUrl <- parseBaseUrl url
  lift $ f manager baseUrl
```

It would also be nice to merge `helper` and `helper1` into a single function which so far I haven't been successful with. I'm still unclear on the original problem but I would assume it's something to do with `getDomain` explicitly using `IO` as the base monad.

Dropping `liftIO $ runExceptT` and the `case` expression as suggested by Benjamin

```haskell
domain
  :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadError ServantError m)
  => Int -> m (Domain)
domain domId = do
  auth <- mkAuth
  helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing

helper
  :: (Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadReader Env m, MonadThrow m)
  => (Manager -> BaseUrl -> m b) -> m b
helper f =  do
  manager <- asks envManager
  url <- asks envBaseUrl
  baseUrl <- parseBaseUrl url
  f manager baseUrl
```

resulted in the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘ExceptT ServantError IO’
  ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        domain :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m,
                    MonadError ServantError m) =>
                   Int -> m Domain
      at <path>
Expected type: m Domain
  Actual type: ExceptT ServantError IO Domain
Relevant bindings include
  domain :: Int -> m Domain
    (bound at <path>)
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing
In the expression:
  do { auth <- mkAuth;
       helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing }
In an equation for ‘domain’:
    domain domId
      = do { auth <- mkAuth;
             helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing }
```

even when using type holes would indicate the return value to be of correct type:

```haskell
domain
  :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadError ServantError m)
  => Int -> m (Domain)
domain domId = do
  auth <- mkAuth
  x <- helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing
  return _

helper
  :: (Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadReader Env m, MonadThrow m)
  => (Manager -> BaseUrl -> m b) -> m b
helper f =  do
  manager <- asks envManager
  url <- asks envBaseUrl
  baseUrl <- parseBaseUrl url
  f manager baseUrl
```

error:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: Domain
Relevant bindings include
  x :: Domain (bound at <path>)
  auth :: AuthenticateReq (AuthProtect "x-api-key")
    (bound at <path>)
  domId :: Int (bound at <path>)
  domain :: Int -> m Domain
    (bound at <path>)
In the first argument of ‘return’, namely ‘_’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return _
In the expression:
  do { auth <- mkAuth;
       x <- helper $ getDomain auth (Just domId) Nothing;
       return _ }
```

Comment: It looks like the type error is coming from the `domain` function. The type checker is deducing `m ~ IO`, for some reason. Can you show us the code for your refactored `domain` function? The version which calls `helper`.

Comment: thank you, updated to include refactored version.

Comment: Lose the `liftIO $ runExceptT` and the `case` expression.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `servant-client` 0.9.*. It wraps up the manager and base url in a `Reader`. That might suffice by itself, but if not, it allows you to use `enter` to change the monad easily.